# Where do we go after death?

Tags: jannah, death, day-of-judgement, grave

I am very confused. When someone dies, people say "He's in a better place" or "He's in paradise inshallah". The thing is, I heard that humans live in the grave first until judgement day and then if they are good they go to paradise. Or after death do they go to paradise directly if they are good? If they stay in the grave, how is life there for the good and bad?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we are alive because of soul. When a person dies his body burried in grave and his soul remain there as mentioned **aalm e barzakh**

yeh it is true if they are good people there soul kept in place **"illeyeen "** 
and others soul kept in place **"sijyeen"**

so in that way you can say soul of good people kept seperate from others..on the day of Judgement soul placed back to body and after **hisab kitab** they will entered in Paradise. hope it clear many of your confusion

you can check out this too: [**islamqa.info**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/200530/where-is-the-soul-and-what-happens-to-it-after-a-person-has-died-and-before-he-is-buried)

Answer (score 1):

Salam there is a place called barazakh were the soul stays till qayamah this is a place between earth and the here after you can listen about it on YouTube interesting topic WELL THAT'S WHAT IS SAID IN ISLAMIC TEXTS.